Failed to start Android emulator with command `emulator -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_30 -writable-system`
Hey guys I am trying to get root of Andriod Studio emulator which version is Android 11("R") x86_64, I was following this blog.
when I do emulator -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_30  -writable-system, the emulator got stucked on bootting. The log is as follow.
 # emulator -avd Pixel_8_Pro_API_30  -writable-system
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 14728
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath D:\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 25552
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARNING | System image is writable
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 120.196.165.24
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 2006:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 2006:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 180c:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 180c:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 812:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 812:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 18:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: 18:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0 (2x)
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: f81d:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0
INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: f81d:c12f:2702:0:50fb:c02f:2702:0 (2x)
WARNING | FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
INFO    | Critical:
INFO    | Warning:
library_mode host gpu mode host
INFO    | Warning:  (6x)
INFO    | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
  Make: 10de
  Model: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER
  Device ID: 2783
I0830 00:18:56.809976   25548 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
added library vulkan-1.dll
createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER
initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
I0830 00:18:56.870044   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
I0830 00:18:56.870119   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: true
I0830 00:18:56.870162   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
I0830 00:18:56.870198   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
I0830 00:18:56.870231   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
I0830 00:18:56.870264   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
I0830 00:18:56.870300   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
I0830 00:18:56.870332   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
I0830 00:18:56.870366   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
I0830 00:18:56.870402   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
I0830 00:18:56.870438   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
I0830 00:18:56.870481   25548 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
I0830 00:18:56.870867   25548 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
I0830 00:18:56.870904   25548 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2)
I0830 00:18:56.870942   25548 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 560.94)
I0830 00:18:56.870975   25548 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OVR_multiview2 GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_buffer
I0830 00:18:56.871026   25548 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
WHPX on Windows 10.0.22631 detected.
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
INFO    | Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
INFO    | Using security allow list from: D:\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib\emulator_access.json
WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
INFO    | The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\25552\jwks\85cca340-fd78-477d-ade9-922c8bda8582\active.jwk
INFO    | Scanning C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\25552\jwks\85cca340-fd78-477d-ade9-922c8bda8582 for jwk keys.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_25552.ini
I0830 00:18:57.030246   24212 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 1344 h 2992 dpiX 480 dpiY 480
I0830 00:18:57.031556   24212 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
INFO    | Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
INFO    | Successfully loaded snapshot 'default_boot'
E0830 00:19:05.668215   22744 FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
E0830 00:19:10.856496   19868 FrameBuffer.cpp:3544] Failed to find ColorBuffer:0
INFO    | Warning:

Anybody can please do me a favor?
Get root of Android 11 on Android Studio emulator

Find solution here
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43320#issuecomment-1992595432
